# How to write data from an AJAX request to DATA in VUE JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

Tell me please, how in DATA to write data from the AJAX response? 
Example:

```
var example = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data:{
        myArr: []
    },
    created: function () {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            this.myArr = data;
        });
    }
  });
```

The problem is that in myArr, the response data is not written. How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: use `this.$set(this.myArr, data)` Here are docs: http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this ? Basically **this** inside the ajax is not exactly the one you would expect.

```
var example = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data:{
        myArr: []
    },
    created: function () {
        var vm = this;
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            vm.myArr = data;
        });
    }
  });
```

You can also use reactivity setting method $set instead of directly assigning to the vm.myArr : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Thank you for help